# GTMOAuth2Authentication with Vimeo

Tags: ios, oauth-2.0, vimeo, vimeo-api

There is a two days left when I started learning about OAuth and I have next problem. I have a some problems with authentication to Vimeo via `GTMOAuth2Authentication`. When I allow permissions to my app, I getting this error on Vimeo:

> "Uh oh, something went wrong! An error has occurred. You won't be able to connect ..."

Please check my code and tell me what is wrong:

```
- (void)authenticate
{
    GTMOAuth2Authentication * auth = [self configuredAuth];

    // Display the authentication view
    GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch * viewController = [[GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch alloc] initWithAuthentication:auth authorizationURL:[NSURL URLWithString:kAuthURL] keychainItemName:kKeychainItemName delegate:self finishedSelector:@selector(viewController:finishedWithAuth:error:)];

    [_parentView presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
} 

-(GTMOAuth2Authentication *)configuredAuth
{
    NSURL * tokenURL = [NSURL URLWithString:kTokenURL];

    NSString * redirectURI = @"com.mytest.app://";
    GTMOAuth2Authentication * auth;

    auth = [GTMOAuth2Authentication authenticationWithServiceProvider:kKeychainItemName
                                                         tokenURL:tokenURL
                                                      redirectURI:redirectURI
                                                         clientID:kClientID
                                                     clientSecret:kClientSecret];
    auth.scope = @"public";
    return auth;
}

- (void)viewController:(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch * )viewController finishedWithAuth:(GTMOAuth2Authentication * )auth error:(NSError * )error
{
    NSLog(@"finished");
    NSLog(@"auth access token: %@", auth.accessToken);

    if (error != nil)
    {
        UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error Authorizing with Vimeo"
                                                         message:[error localizedDescription]
                                                        delegate:nil
                                               cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                               otherButtonTitles:nil];

        NSLog(@"%@", error);

        [alert show];
    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Success Authorizing with Vimeo"
                                                         message:[error localizedDescription]
                                                        delegate:nil
                                               cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                               otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }

    [viewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

I set the same redirect URI in app settings in Vimeo and of course I configured it in my application (i.e. I able to from safari to redirect to my app via `com.mytest.app://`). And of course in `kClientID` and `kClientSecret` defined ID and Secret from developer.vimeo.com.

When I close Auth Controller, I always get this error:

> Error Domain=com.google.GTMOAuth2 Code=-1000 "The operation couldn’t
>   be completed. (com.google.GTMOAuth2 error -1000.)"

It's look like a problem with redirect (callback) URI, but I can't understand what exactly makes a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your redirect URL is correct. It looks like a bundle ID.

```
NSString * redirectURI = @"com.mytest.app://";
```

Have you setup your URL scheme properly ?

Go to **Xcode** -> **Project Settings** -> **Main Target** -> **Info** -> **URL Types**

Make sure that your URL Schemes is setup (you've added a URL Type with the + button), and whatever value you have there matches your redirect uri.

**URL Schemes** = "***testscheme***" --> "***testscheme://***"

Good Luck!